# Constrain latent class choice model coefficient to be positive in gmnl package in R - Error in constrOptim2, initial value not the feasible region

Tags: r, constraints

I'm trying to use the gmnl package to build a latent class choice model. I'd like to constrain a coefficient ($50 discount for seeing a GP, i.e., class.1.Discount$50Discount as below) to be positive (means better than no discount provided). However, an error message pops up:

> Error in constrOptim2(theta = c(class.1.MedProviderGP = 0.513279040827413,  : initial value not the feasible region

```
Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error  z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
class.1.MedProviderGP          -0.2171971  0.1563375  -1.3893 0.1647466    
class.1.FacilityAllAvailable    2.1752389  0.2011631  10.8133 < 2.2e-16 ***
class.1.Discount$50Discount    -0.1849808  0.1874791  -0.9867 0.3238024    
class.1.DiscountEntire_for_50  -0.1649310  0.2735538  -0.6029 0.5465622    
class.1.DiscountEntire_for_100 -0.3601621  0.2389666  -1.5072 0.1317684    
class.1.DiscountEntire_for_200 -0.4968307  0.3203479  -1.5509 0.1209234
```

Meanwhile I am able to add other constrains such as entire discount > $50 discount. No error message for these constraints. Is there any way to make the constrain $50 discount > 0? Or does this mean it is not feasible to set this coefficient to be positive?

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example or at the very least your model call? If you could also explain why you would want to constrain the coefficients and what you hope to achieve, it will be easier to give recommendations as to how you can do what you want.

Comment: Hi, I used below function `LC3.constraint <- gmnl(ConceptChoice ~ MedProvider + Facility + Discount + Wait + Payment|0|0|0|Age40above + EmployPart + EmployOther + TravelDiff + PerceptionHigh + GPCompetenceLow, 
            data = Scenario, 
            model = "lc", Q = 2, 
            panel = T, 
            method = "bfgs",
            constraints = list(ineqA = A, ineqB = B))
summary(LC3.constraint)`

Comment: and for why to constrain the coefficient is because we believe providing some discount for patient should be better i.e. increase their utility of visiting GP than without any discount. So that the discount coefficient should be positive compared with no discount (reference level). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clarification. It appears that this is caused by a starting value problem. You can specify a vector of starting values as follows:

```
# Fill in with the correct values. 
param_start <- c()

# And then add it to your model call with the start option
LC3.constraint <- gmnl(ConceptChoice + MedProvider + Facility + Discount + Wait + Payment| 0 | 0 | 0 | 
                       Age40above + EmployPart + EmployOther + TravelDiff + PerceptionHigh + GPCompetenceLow,
                       data = Scenario, model = "lc", Q = 2, panel = T,
                       method = "bfgs", constraints = list(ineqA = A, ineqB = B),
                       start = param_start)
```

This will allow you to specify a set of starting values that satisfies your constraints and should ensure that the estimation does not fail at starting values.

And now a little unsolicited advice. You are trying to estimate unobserved heterogeneity in your sample by estimating the probability that a patient's choices can be described by one class or the other. With maximum likelihood, the model will choose parameters that maximizes the likelihood of the data. Imposing constraints such as this based on your intuition as a researcher, will lead to inefficient estimation and may even lead to problems with identification. Why not let the data tell you if people perceived the discount in this way? If it doesn't show up in your data even when you increase the number of classes, maybe people did not think about it like this?